# Is there a way to calculate Equal Error Rate (EER) using Weka?

Tags: weka, evaluation

I'm trying to find a way to calculate EER value using Explorer in Weka but without sucess.
I can just see the ROC curve (thereshold curve).

Anyone can show how to find EER value using Weka.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a Weka package to calculate the EER.

The link is:https://sourceforge.net/projects/eer/?source=directory

Best Regards,

Comment: Wow, great stuff! You just helped me save so much time on my Masters degree.